# classcast exception.Getting error in SQL query

Tags: java

I have written a query but it is giving me  java.lang.classcastException
My code is:

```
           String reg1 = (String) ss
                    .createSQLQuery(
                            "select (MAX(id)) as reg from valid_register")
                    .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: clearly your method chain invocation is not giving you `String`  , follow the SO guidelines to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Hibernate api here. Casting to Integer might work here as you are retrieving the max Id. Else please check the datatype of the id field from the table and cast accordingly.